# How to create a new user group and add user to it in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, user-accounts

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.1 Desktop version (32bit).

I want to create a new group called **restricted** which allows its users to use Audio devices and Video devices only, and I want to add a user called **visitors** to that group.

By using **Users and Groups**, I was able to create a new user account called **visitors**, and a new group called **restricted**. But I can't figure out how to add those settings to the group **restricted**, and add the **visitors** user account to that group.

I tried Google-ing, but every search result was about accessing root privileges and all, and I couldn't find answers on this specific topic.

Answer (score 1):

I have answers, but they involve using the command-line.

to set the primary group for a user, you can type

```
sudo usermod -g the_group_name  the_user_name
```

if you want your user to be member of multiple groups (audio, www, or any existing group) you can use

```
sudo usermod -G group1,group3,group3  the_user_name
```

Notice the '-G' (caps)

These command run as root (that's what the 'sudo' is for), so they will ask you to enter your password, but really, there is nothing  scary here. 
Note that you cannot avoid being/becoming (at least temporarily) root to perform users/groups managements tasks under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo adduser follow by username
use sudo adduser username to sudo

su - username to change to your newly created user